# Locating a textbox without any attribute in selenium c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium.

I am working on the selenium webdriver with Visual Studio to automate the web applications and websites.

I need to know how I can locate a textbox and button without any attributes.

Comment: In the worst case scenario, you can find any element using XPath. In general though if you're testing your own software with Selenium, you change the HTML being tested to make it easier to automate by adding classes, attributes or Ids.

Comment: @MartinCostello - I'd upvote if you made it an answer - its the correct (and only) method.

Comment: I did find the solution. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific example in mind or do you just mean in general? If it's specific, share the HTML with us and someone will be able to tell you the best way to locate them. If it's a more general question, you can get the list of available  locator methods in C# from the [dotnet API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/).

If you can't locate an element using its attributes then you usually can still locate it using either CSS or XPath selectors:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("Your CSS Selector Here"));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//Your//XPath//Selector/Here"));
```

Comment: I did find the solution. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If your textbox (`<textarea>` or `<input type="text">`) or button is the only element of the type, you can use `driver.FindElement(By.TagName(" textarea OR input"))`

If that is not the case, and you have no control over the source of the WebApp/WebSite, then you are left only with [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) (as [Martin Costello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064169/martin-costello) commented) or CSS selector (as [George McConnon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3456626/george-mcconnon) answered).

Even then, if the target website has many textboxes, and each of the textboxes is wrapped under same structure like...:

```html
<div>
 <input type = "textbox">
</div>
<div>
 <input type = "textbox">
</div>
<div>
 <input type = "textbox">
</div>
```

...it will get challenging. With XPath, you can choose n-th element that meets the condition (use `//input[n]` or alike). That assumes that the page is *static*. If another textbox/button is added to the page, your XPath [n-th] element selector may return a wrong element. 
I don't think you can do the same with CSS selector all together.

If there is an example of a target WebApp/WebSite, it would be easier to determine the best option for your goal.

Comment: I did find the solution. Thank you so much